# scripts stop working for loaded form - jquery load ajax

Tags: php, drupal, jquery

i am using **drupal** and ihve successfuly loaded a node creation form using jquery load function

```
<div id='test'></div>
<a href='#' id='test2'>test</a>
```

so when clicking link it will load form

```
var ajax_load = "loading...";
var loadUrl = "NODE_CREATE_PATH";
$("#test2").click(function(){           
   $("#test").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);                
});
```

now my problem is all scripts like date popup is not working for this loded form . someone suggested me using http://api.jquery.com/live/ , but i dont know how to use.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Drupal.attachBehaviors() we can :)

example

```
$(id).load(url, function(){
    Drupal.attachBehaviors(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the DOM is being reloaded with the new HTML. Therefore your bindings on these nodes will not work anymore.

You could use: http://api.jquery.com/on/ (the live event is deprecated) for other bindings but not for the datepicker for as far as I know.

You could do something like this:

```
function bindStuff(node) {
    node.find('.datepicker').datepicker();
    // Do some more bindings here
}

$("#test2").click(function(){
   $("#test").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl, function() {
       bindStuff($("#test"));
   });
});

$("#example2").click(function(){
   $("#example").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl, function() {
       bindStuff($("#example"));
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but this will be time consuming ..i want to use it for more forms, is there any simple way like on ajax load, change DOM

Comment: for example , how facebook doing this? binding each function agaian and again! i dont think so

Comment: For events and stuff you can use the jQuery on event type, but not for the datepicker as far as I know. I updated my answer with an example for multiple forms.